# Python - Running Fabric either locally or remotely

Tags: fabric

I have a fabric code which is typically run on a remote machine, but it would be helpful to sometimes run it locally.

I've found two ways  to allow this:

**method #1:** only use the 'run' command (avoid using local) and set up ssh key to be used to this machine on the same machine as if you want to ssh to itself.

**method #2:**

```
from fabric.api import local
from fabric.api import run as run_
def is_local():
    return len(env.hosts) == 0 or env.hosts == ['localhost']

def run(cmd, curr_dir=None):
    if is_local():
        if curr_dir:
            with cd(curr_dir):
                return local(cmd, capture=True)
        else:
            return local(cmd, capture=True)
    else:
        if curr_dir:
            with cd(curr_dir):
                return run_(cmd)
        else:
            return run_(cmd)
```

which limits me in case I want to use some of the operations such as the quiet()...
What do you guys think  is the best solution to be able to run the same code either remotely or locally?
Perhaps there is an additional trick I do not know about.